# how to solve this error in magento?

Tags: magento

> Fatal error: Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract::getMessages(): The
>   script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete
>   object. Please ensure that the class definition
>   "Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection" of the object you are
>   trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or
>   provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in
>   /home/admin/web/exdomainname.com/public_html/inkoffice/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract.php
>   on line 215

when I upload my website on server.magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

That looks to me like an issue with your php configured with `session.auto_start` being on.

You can verify that fact with a file containing

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Look for the section **Session** there, `session.auto_start` **have to** be set to `Off` for Magento to work properly.

[image: phpinfo()]

If that is set to `On`, then adapt your `php.ini` to set that to `Off` or use `php_flag session.auto_start 0` in your `.htaccess` if you don't have access to the edition of your `php.ini` on your server.

Comment: Thank you for help.already define php_flag session.auto_start off in my magento htaccess.magento 1.9.0.1. But when home page load first time but occure error session when refresh page.